# Fancybox autodimensions

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am currently trying to implement fancybox. I want to set it to autodimensions but I am having bug every first load.

```
$.fancybox({

       'autoScale'          : true,
       'autoDimensions'    : true,                
       'content'           : html
});
```

During first load(first click executing on a newly opened browser) the fancybox width and height are not correct but when I try again(click using the opened browser), the fancybox is displaying my desired output. I'm guessing it can't identify the width and height.

The api says
autodimensions

```
For inline and ajax views, resizes the view to the element recieves. Make sure it has dimensions otherwise this will give unexpected results
```

I want to know exactly what 'dimensions' mean... maybe that's why my fancybox is buggy.

I appreciate any help... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dimensions means that the element you are "fancy-boxing" needs to have width and height set, because fancybox will size itself to whatever your content is sized to already.

Also, the problem may be that fancybox is loading before your content does. Try putting the fancybox javascript code at the bottom of your page, just before the  tag.

Comment: The solution was for me to put style="width:500px;height:auto;overflow:hidden" directly on my inline content to be displayed. The css apparently is working but has issue with cross-browser compatibility. Thanks for the tip! I now understand 'dimensions'! :D

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have forgot "," after autoscale:true place it and you will get it working.

Comment: Oops, thank you for mentioning it but I have ',' in my real code... just forgot it here.

Comment: I have tried just by taking the example downloaded from fancy box and replaced the last image from "Different title positions" to the Image Gallery and worked fine.

Comment: And I did not mention autoDimensions and Content in the example and worked well.If you place the entire code for displaying the Images I can help you what I can.

Comment: My content is an html (form) that is a result on my ajax call. Thanks for taking time to reply. I really appreciate it.